# How to cut out a single commit without effect on its children?

Tags: mercurial, commit

imagine this scenario:
- Commit some work with e.g. "Added xy-option".
- After, you realize, that you have forgotten one little detail.
- You add the detail and commit again with "Added xy-option".
- You do some other changes and commit.
- Later you don't like the 2-step commit for xy-option.

So how can one cut out the first commit from history so that in result the changeset for the 2nd commit includes the changes of both?

Answer (score 0):

- `hg help commit` - `--amend` option (when you commit second changeset)
- `hg help -e histedit` - `fold` command